# Haskell: quoteFile fails on text file with "invalid byte sequence" on unicode characters

Tags: linux, haskell, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm facing issue with `quoteFile` in my virtual environment (Debian Wheezy with GHC 7.8.4 installed). I have described file oriented version of `st` quasi quoter from `Text.Shakespeare.Text`:

```hs
import Language.Haskell.TH.Quote    (QuasiQuoter, quoteFile)
import Text.Shakespeare.Text        (st)

sfFile :: QuasiQuoter
stFile = quoteFile st
```

This works very well on my host machine, however, this fails with following error on my virtual environment (a Docker image):

> Exception when trying to run compile-time code:
>     test-file.md: hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)
>
> Code: Language.Haskell.TH.Quote.quoteExp
>           stFile "test-file.md"

I little REPL investigation shows, that error occurs on first unicode character in text file, in my current case this is '«' left-pointer double angle quotation mark:

```
import System.IO (IOMode(..), hGetContents, openFile, openBinaryFile, utf8)

main =
  do h <- openBinaryFile "test-file.md" ReadMode
     hGetContentContents h
     -- Binary read works fine out-of-box.

     h' <- openFile "test-file.md" ReadMode
     hSetEncoding h' utf8
     hGetContentContents h'
     -- This works only if encoding is explicitly set, otherwise 
     -- it gives "invalid byte sequence" error at run-time
```

It seems to me that I need either to configure a bit my virtual environment, or probably rebuild GHC itself.

I tried to set locale to `en.UTF-8 UTF-8`, but it did not help (initially I did no locale configuration at all).

Update: target file has `UTF-8` encoding:

```
$ file -bi test-file.md
text/x-c++; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: Give `hSetEncoding` a try... http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hSetEncoding

Comment: @Arnon the problem is that I have no access to `stFile` quoter's handle, because read operation is internal. Maybe there is a way set default encoding for all handles?

Comment: Not that I know of, without setting it in the environment for the entire OS, which you claim you've already tried.....

Comment: @Arnon I've built GHC from sources in that environment, so maybe I need to rebuilt GHC now with new locales?

Comment: I don't think that'd make a big difference

Comment: @Arnon yep, you are right, this was not helpful. BTW, I've tried `hSetEncoding` and it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I've found that my virtual locale was not properly set, e.g. `locale` command showed me that all `LANG` variables are set to `POSIX`.

Exporting `LANG` variable to command is the quickest workaround (**bash** example):

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF8 cabal build
```

However, likely you need to have `en_US` locale installed, Debian manual configuration is:

1. edit the file `/etc/locale.gen`, append new line `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8`
2. invoke `locale-gen` to generate locales.
3. export `LANG` variable.

Debian locales wiki<sup>[1](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale)</sup>

P.S. My default **Debian Wheezy** installation had `C.UTF-8` in default locales list, so I believe in purposes of minimalism is it possible use it rather than install additional English locale, but I didn't test it by myself.