# Yesod fails to run on docker

Tags: docker, haskell, yesod, haskell-stack

I'm trying to build `yesod` according to [the docs](https://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart) on docker:

```bash
# Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install curl -y
RUN curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh
RUN stack new my-project yesodweb/sqlite
RUN cd my-project && stack install yesod-bin --install-ghc
RUN cd my-project && stack build
```

I get until the next to last step, but then fail:

```
> docker build --tag host_yesod --file Dockerfile .
 => [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:22.04@sha256:6042500cf4b44b  0.0s
 => CACHED [2/7] RUN apt-get update 0.0s
 => CACHED [3/7] RUN apt-get install curl -y 0.0s
 => CACHED [4/7] RUN curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh 0.0s
 => CACHED [5/7] RUN stack new my-project yesodweb/sqlite 0.0s
 => CACHED [6/7] RUN cd my-project && stack install yesod-bin --install-ghc
 => ERROR [7/7] RUN cd my-project && stack build 100.7s
```

Here is the error message:

```
100.6 Error: [S-7282]
100.6        Stack failed to execute the build plan.
100.6
100.6        While executing the build plan, Stack encountered the error:
100.6
100.6        [S-7011]
100.6        While building package language-javascript-0.7.1.0 (scroll up to its section to see the
100.6        error) using:
100.6        /root/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-simple_6HauvNHV_3.6.3.0_ghc-9.2.8 --verbose=1 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/ghc-9.2.8 build --ghc-options ""
100.6        Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

Any ideas how can I fix this?

---

**EDIT**

- I could not find anything relevant in the (huge) logs
- Here are the log messages: [google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1E9Eo39MpDXrjtZ6L9eWnzoFJCMNb8fgNv2ieW0bOdAo/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: not the downvoter, but seems like you haven't really tried to figure out yourself what the problem is? e.g. it says "scroll up to its section to see error" but you don't post that port of the error message...

Comment: @mb21, I pasted the entire (*huge*) log message of the docker, and searched it. I couldn't find anything interesting - therefore I did not add it to the question.

Comment: The `javascript` mentioned dependency is implicit, and so I don't know where to fix that

Comment: if you cannot find the relevant part, then maybe post the whole error message?

Comment: @mb21, sure I'll do that

Comment: @mb21, I added a link to a google doc containing the entire log message (17 pages long in font 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you're looking for is

```
92.67 language-javascript
  > happy: src/Language/JavaScript/Parser/Grammar7.y:
  hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)
```

Googling `"docker" hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)` tells us that this means the source code file is not UTF-8 and leads to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30436634). So try appending the line `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8` to the `/etc/locale.gen` file in your docker image.

Comment: It worked ! (with some minor adjustments) - I'll publish the complete `Dockerfile` as a separate answer. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

This answer is mostly an addendum for [mb21's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214446/mb21) answer with the complete Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install curl -y
RUN curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh
RUN stack new my-project yesodweb/sqlite
RUN cd my-project && stack install yesod-bin --install-ghc
RUN apt-get install -y locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
RUN cd my-project && export LANG=en_US.UTF8 && stack build
```

It aggregates the mentioned reference with [this additional answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39761477/3357352).